# Creating array through macro

Tags: c

I have school homework, almost done, but I noticed a little detail in specification and I dont know how to do it.

Specification looks like this:
Define these macros for bit arrays:

**BitArray(arrayname, size)**

//Defines and nullifies bit field. You must make it local/automatic. (Not sure if the translation is right, I couldn't find much about "automatic" fields...) I understand it as I have to make macro like this (that I can't use dynamic memory (malloc)):

```
#define BitArray(arrayname,size) unsigned long bits[size+some operations]
```

**typedef BitArray_t**

And there comes my problem, because we have to use new type, which is used in all other functions for passing bit arrays. I have no idea how to define it in header file. When I go like this:

```
Headerfile.h
typedef unsigned long *bits; // 

//We also have to storage size of the bit array. So I can either put it in 0th array element, or make struct (there came even more problems)

#define SetBit(array, index, value)\
{\
     ...\
     1 << position & array[2];\ // PROBLEM
     ...\
}
```

Problem here. It tells me I compare two different types. If I put *array, it works of course, but I didnt 
want to create array of pointers and I believe I just do something wrong. Is it possible to make array of my typedef without having to deference it every time? I am not sure if I wrote it clear, but I hope you will understand me at least a bit.

Comment: automatic/local generally means that the memory is just stack allocated and in the scope of some function/method... automatic is the memory class and local is the scope, they get used interchangeably a bit.

Comment: First off, just want to make sure that you know that a bit field is an array in which each bit of the elements represents a 1 or 0 value. For example, each unsigned long may be able to store 64 different values. You know how this works, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a struct for the bit array

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int size,
    unsigned long bits[];
} BitArray_t;
```

The way I would initialize this on the stack would be as follows

```
#define BITS_PER_BYTE 8

unsigned int size = 1024;

/* add 1 here in case the size is not evenly divisible by number of bits 
   in unsigned long */
unsigned int bit_arr_size = (size / sizeof(unsigned long) / BITS_PER_BYTE) + 1;

unsigned int bits[bit_arr_size] = {0}; /* this initializes the entire array */

/* Name of the struct is going to be a_bitarray */
/* struct initialization */
BitArray_t a_bitarray = { .size = bit_arr_size, .bits = bits };
```

Converting that to a macro

```
#define BitArray(arrayname, size) \
unsigned int bit_arr_size = ((size) / sizeof(unsigned long) / 8) + 1; \
unsigned int bits[bit_arr_size] = {0}; /* this initializes the entire array */ \
BitArray_t arrayname = { .size = bit_arr_size, .bits = bits };
```

Comment: You can't initialise flexible array like that. And it uses VLA, which may be missing.